# Ouestion About topology and Compactness

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set R of real numbers with the topology:
$$T = \{(-\infty,a) \mid a \in \Bbb R\} \cup \{\Bbb R, \varnothing\}$$

I would like to determine whether $(-\infty,1]$ is compact or not. I think it is compact but how can I show? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an open cover $(-\infty,1]$. There must be an open set that contains $1$. Let it be $(-\infty,x)$ where $x>1$.

Then, in fact, that open set covers the whole set.

So in fact, not only we do we have the fact that every open cover has **finite** subcover, we even have the fact that every open cover has **one-set** subcover.

Comment: Thank you I understand..

Answer (score 0):

Hint: take an open covering family, $(U_i)$ of $(-\infty,1]$, one of the open set contains $1$, what it should be ?